# PowerGREP - regular expression

Tags: regex, powergrep

I have log of Apache and each line of file looks like:

```
script.php?variable1=value1&variable2=value2&variable3=value3&.........................
```

I need to take out this part of string:

```
variable1=value1&variable2=value2
```

and ignore the rest of line. How I can do this in PowerGREP?

I tried:

```
variable1=(.*)&variable2=(.*)&
```

But I get rest of line after value2.

Please help me, sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what Ed Cottrell wrote about his second example, the first one works better (i. e. correctly); this is because if the subexpression for `value2` is made non-greedy, it matches as few characters as possible, i. e. not any.

---

If you wouldn't mind having the `&` after `value2` included in the match, you could as well hone your try by making the subexpression for `value2` non-greedy, so that it only extends to the next `&`:

```
variable1=(.*)&variable2=(.*?)&
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `.` with `[^&]` and drop the final `&`, like this:

```
variable1=(.*)&variable2=([^&]*)
```

`.` will match anything it can (any character except for the newline character, basically). `[^&]`, on the other hand, matches only characters that are not `&`.

For even better results and faster performance, you can also replace the first `.` in the same way and add `?` (the non-greedy qualifier), like so:

```
variable1=([^&]*?)&variable2=([^&]*?)
```

Here's a [**working demo**](https://regex101.com/r/vG0vT2/3).